# How can I check if a resource group is created in Azure using the resource_group class with Python

Tags: python, azure

So, after creating a resource group with the below code, I want to check if it has been created. I saw some examples with code that use resorcse_groups.check_exists(resource_group_name), but I didn't see it in the Microsoft documentation.

```
def create_resource_group(self):
    resource_group_region = {'location': region_name}
    resource_group_name = self.resource_client.resource_groups.create_or_update(
        self.config.resource_group, resource_group_region
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find something related to the "check_exists" method but here is one of the workarounds where we list the resource groups in the subscription and use the if condition.

```py
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
from azure.mgmt.resource import ResourceManagementClient

GROUP_NAME = "<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>"
subscription_id = "<YOUR_SUBSCRIPTION_ID>"

credentials = DefaultAzureCredential()
client = ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)

for item in client.resource_groups.list():
    if(item.name==GROUP_NAME):
        print("The resource group exists")
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]